# "\" Line break makes pandas dataframe columns reorder alphabetically

Tags: python, pandas

My code got too big, so I started using "\" for better readability. I've noticed however, that my columns got reorder alphabetically by doing this.

Does anyone know how to stop this from happening?

Here's the code:

```
def unsettled_event(team_name,market):
    """Returns all bets tied to this specific event."""
    combos_list = df[(df["home"] == team_name) \
                     & (df["profit"].isnull()) \
                     & (df["market"] == market) \
                     & (df['settled_date']).isnull()].combo_id.dropna().unique()
    df_combos = df[df["combo_id"].isin(combos_list)].sort_values("combo_id") \
                [["combo_id", "home", "market", "odds", "selection", "bookmaker", "broker", "stake_adj", "is_won"]] 
    df_singles = df[(df["home"] == team_name) \
                    & (df["leg_size"] == 1) \
                    & (df["profit"].isnull()) \
                    & (df["market"] == market) \
                    & (df['settled_date']).isnull()] \
                [["combo_id", "home", "market", "selection", "odds", "bookmaker", "broker", "stake_adj", "is_won"]]
    return pd.concat([df_singles, df_combos], ignore_index=True)
```

So in the end, df.columns is returning:

```
['bookmaker', 'broker', 'combo_id', 'home', 'is_won', 'market', 'odds', 'selection', 'stake_adj']
```

And it should return:

```
["combo_id", "home", "market", "selection", "odds", "bookmaker", "broker", "stake_adj", "is_won"]
```

Comment: Added the code.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by your columns getting reordered alphabetically? Do you mean that the *displayed* order of the columns is alphabetically by their respective names?

Comment: Yes, please check the edit.

Comment: It does matter for readability.

Comment: Thanks for the brackets advice. Will specify columns in the end then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the relevant columns displayed in a specific order, specify them in your output:

```
df[["combo_id", "home", "market", "selection", "odds", "bookmaker", 
    "broker", "stake_adj", "is_won"]].head()
```

Under the hood, the order doesn't matter. If it matters in the output, you're better off being explicity about it.

(Note that more than half of the time, it turns out it also doesn't matter in the output.)

---

You also don't need the backslashes.

For example, this is fine, and more Python style:

```
def unsettled_event(team_name,market):
    """Returns all bets tied to this specific event."""
    columns = ["combo_id", "home", "market", "selection", "odds",
               "bookmaker", "broker", "stake_adj", "is_won"]
    combos_list = df[(df["home"] == team_name)
                     & (df["profit"].isnull())
                     & (df["market"] == market)
                     & (df['settled_date']).isnull()].combo_id.dropna().unique()
    df_combos = df[df["combo_id"].isin(combos_list)].sort_values("combo_id")[columns]     
    df_singles = df[(df["home"] == team_name)
                    & (df["leg_size"] == 1)
                    & (df["profit"].isnull())
                    & (df["market"] == market)
                    & (df['settled_date']).isnull()][columns]
    return pd.concat([df_singles, df_combos], ignore_index=True)
```

There are probably a few more changes that you could make, remove some redundant parts, but this is the gist of it. The `[...]` will keep things together, despite the newlines in between them.

Comment: Defining columns in the beginning definitely helps it. Thanks!